# Проблема с кодировкой базы данных

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных, кодировка, jdbc

Есть метод, который отсылает запрос к БД:

```
void selectTranslationQuery(PreparedStatement preparedStatement,DbWorker dbWorker,String dbQuery,String date,String dateGmt, String postContent,String postTitle, String postInheritStatus,String postCommentStatus,String postPingStatus, String guid,String postTypeRevision){
    try {
        preparedStatement=dbWorker.getConnection().prepareStatement(dbQuery);
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, 2);
        preparedStatement.setString(2,date);
        preparedStatement.setString(3, dateGmt);
        preparedStatement.setString(4, postContent);
        preparedStatement.setString(5, "footlivehd.com");
        preparedStatement.setString(6, postTitle);
        preparedStatement.setString(7, postInheritStatus);
        preparedStatement.setString(8, postCommentStatus);
        preparedStatement.setString(9, postPingStatus);
        preparedStatement.setString(10, "to_ping");
        preparedStatement.setString(11, "pinged");
        preparedStatement.setString(12, date);
        preparedStatement.setString(13, dateGmt);
        preparedStatement.setString(14, "post_filtered");
        preparedStatement.setString(15, guid);
        preparedStatement.setString(16, postTypeRevision);
        preparedStatement.execute();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

В ответ получаю знаки вопроса в базe данных.
Кодировка в базе UTF-8.
Пробовал слать текст в базу при вызове метода вот так:

```
URLEncoder.encode(newsService.getNewsHeader(href)+translationText, "UTF-8"),
```

В ответ получил `D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD+%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD`
В чем может быть дело?

**Обновление**

Пробовал в параметрах URL к БД добавить

```
URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
```

Ловлю

> java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported character encoding 'utf8 '

У меня ubuntu, может здесь проблема.

Comment: Urlencode - это вообще из другой оперы. Вот табличка - http://cyclowiki.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%8F%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8B , она поможет сориентироваться, что там с кодировками (из какой в какую надо перекодировать). А для перекодирования нужно что-то типа этого: http://www.sources.ru/java/faq/encodings.htm но в джаве я не спец.

Comment: И еще второй вариант - после создания подключения к БД задать в параметрах сессии нужную кодировку (это даже лучше). Но там у каждой СУБД свой синтаксис и свои особенности.

Comment: Тег mysql добавьте, тогда mysql-щики вам подскажут.

Comment: попробуйте в url варианты `characterEncoding=utf-8` или `characterEncoding=UTF-8`
И проверьте какая кодировка уставлена на эту конкретную таблицу

Comment: @Dmitry Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Comment: @Alexandr спасибо, получилось)
Кроме этого запятую убрал из запроса)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в url варианты `characterEncoding=utf-8` или `characterEncoding=UTF-8` и проверьте какая кодировка уставлена на эту конкретную таблицу.